# Average seed to fruit length of apache chili pepper

Tags: chili

What is the average time between seed (including germination) to fruit (first harvest) of the apache chili pepper plant grown in an ideal environment?

If anyone knows a good source of data for such values of other plants, that'll be grand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Time to harvest: 5 - 6 months

Source: The Complete Book of Plant Propagation, Mitchell Beazley (1997) p.207